# New session creating by Unity3d WWW form request

Tags: php, session, unity-game-engine, server

We developed a game in unity3d.It tries to get information stored in Session by requesting WWW form to PHP file.And PHP trying to pass Seiion data back to Unity.
But the problem is When unity sends a request to PHP a new session id is generating instead of taking the present session id only.
I am confused because the same code working in my another server but not in new dedicated server.Is there any server setting issue.Please guide on this.

Comment: Do you send Session ID to your server?

Comment: No.Why should I?Unity runs in a same session.So it has to take the same session right!

Comment: How can you know which session is this client? If there are so many user?

Comment: I got the problem.It was some server setting issue!!I need not to pass session id to Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.We hosted in one server and one domain was pointing to that.But Client wanted another domain also pointing to that perticular Server.So IT team was redirecting the first domain to second domain.While this redirection was happenning, every time new session was creating.So I was thinking my session was losing.

Hope It would help for Someone!!